# Updating multiple node fields

Tags: nodes

Is there a module that allows the user to update multiple node fields in one page?

I found a method using Views (http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/12/13/drupal-7-update-multiple-nodes-at-once-in-a-views/), but I prefer to use module approach. Probably something that utilizes function `node_mass_update` (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.admin.inc/function/node_mass_update/7)

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews will do this for you one of the safest and easiest way

Answer (score 1):

I guess my first question is *how* many nodes are you looking to update. If it's a relatively small amount, you should just use VBO (per the article you referenced). That is the easiest *contributed* module method of updating multiple nodes.

However, it is possible for you to create your own module (i.e. `custom_node_update`) and run the `node_mass_update` upon form submission (as recommended by the API documentation). This will be especially useful if you are updating a large number of nodes because it will batch it appropriately, however, you'll be required to write some custom code.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The number of nodes varies from as little as one to as many as 50 nodes. I was hoping there was a module available for that, so I don't have to write something that has already existed.